# Select rows from a Pandas DataFrame with same values in one column but different value in the other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, rows

Say I have the pandas DataFrame below:

```
   A      B     C   D
1  foo    one   0   0
2  foo    one   2   4
3  foo    two   4   8
4  cat    one   8   4
5  bar    four  6  12
6  bar    three 7  14
7  bar    four  7  14
```

I would like to select all the rows that have equal values in A but differing values in B. So I would like the output of my code to be:

```
   A      B    C   D
1  foo    one  0   0
3  foo    two  4   8
5  bar  three  7  14
6  bar    four 7  14
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I have approximately 11,000 rows with a lot of variation in the column values, but this situation comes up a lot. In my dataset, if elements in column A are equal then the corresponding column B value should also be equal, however due to mislabeling this is not the case and I would like to fix this, it would be impractical for me to do this one by one.

Comment: Why is cat one missing?

Comment: cat one is missing because there is no other row such that 'cat' is its A value but 'one' is not its B value. maybe my post wasn't clear enough, sorry.

Answer (score 11):

You can try  `groupby()` + `filter` + `drop_duplicates()`:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep="first")
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  4   8
4  bar   four  6  12
5  bar  three  7  14
```

OR, in case you want to drop duplicates between the subset of columns `A` & `B` then can use below but that will have the row having `cat` as well.

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep="first")
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  4   8
3  cat    one  8   4
4  bar   four  6  12
5  bar  three  7  14
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) + [head](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
result = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).groupby(['A', 'B']).head(1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  4   8
4  bar   four  6  12
5  bar  three  7  14
```

The first group-by and filter will remove the rows with no duplicated `A` values (i.e. `cat`), the second will create groups with same `A, B` and for each of those get the first element.

Comment: When I try this, I get: `unhashable type: 'dict'`. For reference `type(df)` returns : `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` and `type(df.A)` returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: what are the types of df.A?

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are correct and may be more sophisticated too. If you have complex criteria, [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) function will be very useful. If you are like me and want to keep things simple, i feel following is more beginner friendly way

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'cat', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
    'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'four', 'three', 'four'],
    'C': [0,2,4,8,6,7,7],
    'D': [0,4,8,4,12,14,14]
}, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

>>> df = df.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], keep='last')
    A       B       C   D
2   foo     one     2   4
3   foo     two     4   8
4   cat     one     8   4
6   bar     three   7   14
7   bar     four    7   14


>>> df = df[df.duplicated(['A'], keep=False)]
    A       B       C   D
2   foo     one     2   4
3   foo     two     4   8
6   bar     three   7   14
7   bar     four    7   14
```

`keep='last'` is optional here